# Text painted over QT QGLWidget looks distorted

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to paint text over my QOpenGLWidget however the test looks all distorted. It looks like something to do with transparency...

This is my drawing code:

```
void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{

    QPainter painter;
    painter.begin(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.beginNativePainting();

    // Paint to frame buffer first
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    setView();
    renderGeometry(m_prgMesh);
    renderGrid();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    painter.endNativePainting();
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing);
    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10));
    painter.drawText(10,20, QString("Sample string"));
    //painter.drawText(10,10, QString("Cursor position: %1,%2").arg(QString::number(m_cursorPos.x()), QString::number(m_cursorPos.y())));
    painter.end();
    update();
}
```

And this is how the text looks:
[image]

I am using QT 5.4

Comment: It's better to use complementary color (e.g. yellow in your case) to demonstrate the distorted text : )

Comment: Why are you using `QGLWidget` in Qt 5.4? It's better to use  `QOpenGLWidget` and the `QOpenGL` classes because `QGLWidget` and `QGL` classes are obsolete and you should not use them in new code.

Comment: Sorry a mistake on my part, I actually using a QOpenGLWidget

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found the problem.
It was actually in one of the drawing functions before the text.
Somewhere in the code there was:
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,  GL_LINE);
So placing:
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK,  GL_FILL);
Just before the text drawing fixed the issue.